# Как правильно сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, морфология

*Оконцевание, оконечивание* или *терминирование концов кабеля* — как правильно сказать?

Comment: заголовок вопроса должен быть информативным и содержать суть вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Ну это скорее к специалистам по кабелям вопрос, а не по русскому языку.
Такие вещи словарями обычно не нормируются.
В принципе термины *оконцевание* и *терминирование* встречаются, но насколько они правильны - сказать не могу. Зато "на слух" мне ближе "оконечивание". Может потому, что этот термин используется не только по отношению к кабелю.   
~~~~~

Добавлено. Я вот подумал, скорее всего все три варианта не совсем удачны. 
Английский вариант понятно плох потому, что это прямой перенос, а оба русских означают наличие на кабеле некоего устройства, называемого концом или оконечником. Насколько знаю, разъёмную фишку на конце кабеля так не называют.
А термин "завершение кабеля" совсем уже вышел из моды, не знаете? Он бы был самым правильным.

Comment: Цитата: "...а оба русских означают наличие на кабеле некоего устройства, называемого концом или оконечником".
Совершенно верно! Идет речь о монтаже на конец кабеля какого-либо устройства, в частности - разъема.

Вот ту самую разъемную фишку на конце кабеля иногда называют терминатор.

Comment: Может, Вам стоит сменить метки? Например, на "морфология" или "грамотная-речь"? По таким странным меткам как "оконечивание" Вас точно не заметят!

Comment: Спасибо, сменил. Я тут новенький :)

Comment: Про фишку я знаю. Не одну сотню таких сделал.  
Но я никогда не слышал, что бы её (вернее его - интерфейс) кто-либо называл оконечником или концом. А без этого предлагаемые глаголы нельзя назвать удачными, поскольку они буквально означают создание "конца", "окончания" или "оконечника".  
  
Но конец - это как на флоте: веревка, а не то, что к ней на конце привязано. А "оконечник" - это вообще из другой области, буровой.

Comment: Т.е. мой пример является сленгом, и в технической документации его применять нельзя?

Comment: Я не был столь категоричен.  
То, что сленг - да, пожалуй.  
А что нельзя употреблять - это не в моей (и не в вашей) компетенции. Ну как языку запретишь употреблять "неправильный" термин, если нет правильного?  
А в техничекой документации, имхо, можно все, что априорно понятно читающему и не вызывает возражений со стороны власти предержащей. И даже то, что не очень понятно, но оговорено заранее.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения.